# Insert text of child in respective parent data element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to put the text values of the children in their respective parents data element, but I am getting all the values together.
Here is my code:

HTML

```
<ul>

<li class="item" data-v="1">
  <div class="xyz" data-v="2">
    <div class="abc" data-v="3">AED 12,00.00</div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="item" data-v="1">
  <div class="xyz" data-v="2">
    <div class="abc" data-v="3">AED 13,00.00</div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="item" data-v="1">
  <div class="xyz" data-v="2">
    <div class="abc" data-v="3">AED 15,00.00</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Jquery:

```
    var eee = $('.abc').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
    $('.abc').parents('.item').attr('data-v', eee);
```

Result is like this:

```
    <li class="item" data-v="1200.001300.001500.00">...</li>
    <li class="item" data-v="1200.001300.001500.00">...</li>
    <li class="item" data-v="1200.001300.001500.00">...</li>
```

What I want is:

```
   <li class="item" data-v="1200.00">...</li>
   <li class="item" data-v="1300.00">...</li>
   <li class="item" data-v="1500.00">...</li>
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're retrieving the `text()` from *all* `.abc` elements, then applying back to *all* the `.item` elements. Instead you need to loop over each of them and perform the logic individually, like this:

```js
$('.abc').each(function() {
  var $abc = $(this);
  var text = $abc.text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
  $abc.closest('.item').attr('data-v', text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li class="item" data-v="1">
    <div class="xyz" data-v="2">
      <div class="abc" data-v="3">AED 12,00.00</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-v="1">
    <div class="xyz" data-v="2">
      <div class="abc" data-v="3">AED 13,00.00</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item" data-v="1">
    <div class="xyz" data-v="2">
      <div class="abc" data-v="3">AED 15,00.00</div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Also note that unless you specifically need to have the `data-v` attribute available in the DOM I'd suggest using `data('v', text)` instead, as it's more performant.

Comment: Thanks ur code is working but the first approach of the attr selector is working only the second approach is not. i.e the data element selector.
Maybe because of the jquery version.

Comment: For the second version to work you need to retrieve the value through `data()` as well, ie. `var data = $(el).data('v');` - but I'm glad the first version works for you

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution as following:

```
    $('.abc').parents('.item').attr('data-v', function(){
return  $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")
});
```

Comment: Thanks your approach is working also and its quite simple as well.

Comment: we can also achieve it by .closest function